# Wrap Azure B2C Authentication Token in RXjs Http Get Method

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, rxjs, restful-authentication

I have RXJS Http get method in Angular 5 to consume services from ASP.Net Web 2. Before I am make call to consume these services, I have already got authentication token that I have received from Azure B2C.

My question is how I wrapped this RXJS service method to pass token along with Web API request.

### Service

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import{ IMessageA } from '../../../Interfaces/UnitTest/TestMessageA';

@Injectable()

 export class ServerFlowTestService{

   private developmentBaseUrl: string = 'https://localhost:44370/';

   constructor(private http: Http){}

   public getMessageFromWebAPI_T1():Observable<IMessageA[]>
  {
    return this.http.get(this.developmentBaseUrl+ '/app/analysis/GetMessage')
                    .map((response:Response)=> <IMessageA[]>response.json())

  }
}
```

### Observable Component

```
unitTestA: IMessageA[];

  constructor(private authSandbox: AuthenticationSandbox, private unitTestingService: ServerFlowTestService 

 ) { 

 this.token = authSandbox.getToken();

 this.unitTest1 = unitTestingService.getServerFlowTest1();

 this.unitTestingService.getMessageFromWebAPI_T1()
                      .subscribe((messageA_Data) => this.unitTestA = messageA_Data);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [angular2-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-jwt) package to make a wrapper. It grabs your `token` from `local`/`sessionStorage` and wraps the necessary headers. You create an `AuthModule` which you import into your main module:

```
import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';

export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) 
{
    return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
        tokenName: 'token',
        tokenGetter: (() => sessionStorage.getItem('adal.idtoken')),
        globalHeaders: [{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }],
    }), http, options);
}

@NgModule({
    providers: [
    {
        provide: AuthHttp,
        useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
        deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
    }
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

and then you can use `AuthHttp` to call with the `token` instead of `http`:

```
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';

constructor(private authHttp: AuthHttp) { }

public getMessageFromWebAPI_T1():Observable<IMessageA[]>
{
    return this.authHttp.get(this.developmentBaseUrl+ '/app/analysis/GetMessage')
                .map((response:Response)=> <IMessageA[]>response.json())

}
```

Check out [this walk through](https://blogs.msmvps.com/shareblog/2017/06/11/accessing-net-core-apis-from-angular2-using-azure-ad/), especially the Authorization part. Hope this helps.